# Batch file to open multiple instances of cmd and run Ruby script in each instance

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file, cmd, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to open multiple instances of cmd up which each run a ruby script at the same time.  For background into the scripts, each of these ruby scripts run watir-webdriver and spawn new browser instances.  All of this should happen instantaneously.

Here's what I've tried:

```
start cmd /k
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
ruby script_1.rb
start cmd /k
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
ruby script_2.rb
start cmd /k
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
ruby script_3.rb
```

However, only two cmd prompts opened and in the second one it just sits at the C:\Users\test\Desktop and doesn't run the command.  I commented out each of the three ruby commands and then ran it and it opened up all three cmd prompts.

Comment: Why do you need to run cmd? `start /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" ruby script_1.rb` should open a new console window.

Comment: Ah okay, I've never done batch scripting before so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try next approach:

```
pushd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
start "1" cmd /k ruby script_1.rb
start "2" cmd /k ruby script_2.rb
start "3" cmd /k ruby script_3.rb
```